# Project specific local repository in maven

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Is there a maven equivalent of Node.js `npm i` which fetchs all the dependencies under `node_modules` directory, or Ruby `bundle install --path <directory-path>`?

I'm looking for a way to manage the dependencies written in `pom.xml` on the project's own responsibility. Without anything, all the artifacts are downloaded into `~/.m2/repository` which is shared by all existing maven projects.

The version of maven is 3.1.1. Is there any good idea?

Comment: Sharing a repository is fine. In Maven it acts more like a cache. A better optimization would be to use a Maven repository manager like Nexus or Artifactory.

Answer (score 2):

If you really like to change the repository for every project you can use the following:

```
mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=/WhatEverDirYouLike clean install
```

but it contradicts to the idea of the local repository.